# Replacing three AAA batteries with a 3.7 V, 1200 mAh lithium battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-polymer

I have earmuffs that use three AAA  batteries that need to be replaced after one day's worth of continuous use.

I was wondering if I could replace these batteries with a 3.7 V, 1200 mAh lithium battery similar to [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32996546051.html) from AliExpress? I already have one from another project, so it saves buying rechargeable AAA batteries and a charger.

I also have a TP4056 lithium battery charger similar to [this one](https://www.surplustronics.co.nz/products/10385-micro-usb-5v-1a-18650-tp4056-lithium-battery-charger) which will all fit within the old AAA battery case.

Is this setup likely to damage the earmuffs at all? I have temporarily attached the battery on its own without the TP4065, and the earmuffs work fine.

Any assistance or recommended reading for a beginner would be appreciated.

Comment: Might work ok.   My fear would be putting some AliExpress procured lithium battery right next to my ear.

Comment: @KyleB haha that's a good point. I'll be honest the earmuff itself looks like it came from aliexpress so i have probably been running that risk for a few years now. Worth thinking about though.

Comment: The difference is Alkaline or Carbon-Zinc AAA's don't have a propensity to violently and without provocation catch fire like Lithium do!!!!

Comment: @WillNZ , I supplemented as an Addendum on my answer with reading links I believe will bring further confidence for your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About replacement of 3x AAA by 1x Lithium:**

AAA batteries can be either Zinc-Carbon, Alkaline or NiMH. Working voltages then can be as high as 3x1.6 = 4.8V to as low as 3x1.0 = 3V.
This voltage range (3.0 to 4.8V) is well covered by 1x protected Lithium cell (2.8~3.0V to 4.2V).
So, **about voltage range - YES**, you can replace the battery source to one lithium cell, without major modifications, apart from the Charger itself, as you linked.

**About reliability of the Lithium cell and charger**:

As you somehow mentioned, several more affordable consumer items are purchased with less than stellar reviews and traceability, but still “work OK”. As most TP4056 modules and lithium cell work acceptably,  I would give a try and do this “upgrade” and monitor the start-end charging and discharging/cutoff of the lithium+TP4056, still outside the headphone.  Please also observe the IC controlling the Li-Po cell:
[image]

Moreover, the battery itself may have its own battery management IC, as highlighted in above picture and vendor’s post:
[image].
Because of that built in protection the use of an  already protected Lithium cell + TP4056 may be redundant and eventually cause interference.

**Prototype Testing and Verifications**:
Some further investigation may be good: , using these 2 parts are necessary and work ok. I would also check for overcurrent:  planning a test to use resistive loads to check the said overvoltage, undervoltage and overcurrent works as expected.

As most probably everything will run fine, you may not even need the TP4056, because the built-in protection does all that. Check this [video from Kasyan TV](https://youtu.be/zavSoXgzhxg) about these protection modules.

**Final assembly**:
After these tests, I would make the final adjustments and overhaulings, as a cabling and charging port connection, etc.

---

### Addendum & further readings:

Although the OP has already accepted the answer, I found some information of certain “[TP4056 + DW01A + FS8205 module](https://www.sunrom.com/p/lithum-battery-charger-with-protection-microusb)” (google it), like the one the OP might use.
The following picture (from [here](https://www.sunrom.com/p/lithum-battery-charger-with-protection-microusb)) is from a TP4056 with Protection Circuit:
[image]

Such module has the following block diagram [from here](https://acoptex.com/project/9446/basics-project-082a-lithum-battery-charger-tp4056-at-acoptexcom/), where it further details and explains the module features:
[image]

Additional ”hack” using TP4056 + LiPo battery are worth to see [here](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html), [here](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056-page2.html) and on another [Q&A here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/446535/248404).

Comment: thank you so much for your comprehensive answer. I really appreciate the time taken and the depth of knowledge shared with myself and others. Cheers