# Can I switch left/right the pins usage of FS8205A?

Tags: battery-charging, protection, pins

I'm looking at [FS8205A](https://www.ic-fortune.com/eng/new_product1_3_1.asp?pno=FS8205A) ([Datasheet](https://www.ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/FS8205A-DS-17_EN.pdf)). To me as a hobbyist, it looks to be symmetrical, left/right. I'm going to combine it with DW01 for a battery protection circuit. Is there something that will cause issues if I switch the use of pins 2,3,4 with 7,6,5 (because of layout)? [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446526/how-does-the-dw01a-prevent-overcharging-and-discharging) there is a diagram with the pins.

Comment: (There seems to be a SOT-23-6L variant - symmetrical, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand there shouldn't be any issue since from a circuit point of view its the same. Its a back to back MOSFET to implement a switch which can control current flow as ON, OFF or allow only in one direction through body diode. So S1/G1 can be swapped with S2/G2.