# TP4056 module series output

Tags: batteries, circuit-protection, tp4056

I'm trying to wire five [TP4056](http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf) modules in series to produce enough voltage to power a motor. The batteries I'm using are identical 13400 lithium-ion batteries, which are connected to the module.

However, the problem I have is that the output is taken from only one of the modules in the circuit when I check it with a multimeter. When I try to check the voltage of some of the individual modules, the output voltage reads zero, and only one of them shows the voltage that is going through to the end. Am I wiring this wrong, and if so, what could I do to fix it?

edit: The motor I use is a 775 motor bought from [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/394369188645?hash=item5bd23c4325:g:SkoAAOSw5g5jkZHM&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4LKVvuX78Qx9FVgrgNPQLKhVPbZgBn0vqLiwJLvdyED9OmyH1T%2BaN%2F3TOAcc%2FXr9DvxgP1xkT61UIUj392pndk3I4pTAHMZ2VBXb1sWalOZhBMcSXkoKszJGU3DdlpTN7uIjn0W1GERU3Tn2kKqSmwHIPWLnbwXZwFlQmnygF%2Bb2zpKOYYVVFAhGWLQIA055igoglG4c4ciV%2FHVrzzP2sYaBnp3X93%2F4pj7VBAw1XlyUJSREenKw6zwEN5SRbkJfoul5IIG%2F12O4ZSD3NrppGIQ9HN%2FuoOT01HsyXne%2FpxmB%7Ctkp%3ABFBMiOuctrRh) eBay link. The rated voltage is 12-36 V and the rated current is 0.32 A.

Wiring diagram of what I have currently:
[image: Wiring diagram of what I have currently]

TP4056 module schematic:
[image: TP4056 module schematic]

Comment: Can you post the motor specifications? (Edit the question.)

Comment: @JYelton edited the question with the motor specification. The motor isn't the issue though, the batteries/modules behave the same with or without load.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the problem you are having is in wiring the charger modules together in series. The cells in series would add voltage and share current, but you're effectively inserting the FS8205A FETs and DW01A protection IC between every battery. There's actually [a great question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/446526/2028) [and answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/446535/2028) about this very circuit you should check out.

[image: Charger module schematic with current paths shown]

<sup>[Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/446535/2028)</sup>

Huisman's answer shows that during discharge, the current path is as shown by the red line. The battery protection circuit is monitoring the voltage drop across the dual FET, which is likely calibrated for a single cell. When you connect additional ones in series, this voltage/current is not in the expected range, and the protection circuit switches the FETs off.

By connecting six cells in series (I'll use 3.7 V 400 mAh as the specifications for the 13400 cells) you would be creating a 22.2 volt battery, which should be OK as far as your motor is concerned. The problem is that the cells aren't strictly in series, because of the intervening protection circuits.

I'm not that familiar with these modules that you are using, but my expectation is that they are designed to work with a single cell and not be wired in series with others. You could disconnect the cells from the charging circuits and connect them strictly in series to power the motor, then remove them from the circuit entirely and charge them individually.

The linked datasheet for the TP4056 lists in features (emphasis mine):

> Charges **Single Cell** Li-Ion Batteries Directly from USB Port

My recommendation is to keep these chargers *out* of the current path to get the desired voltage and performance, or to look for a multi-cell charger (sometimes called a balance charger) that is designed for this sort of application.